# formatting char*, similiar to "printf", but without printing out

Tags: c

Given a `char *str = "something %s something2 %d"`, how can I format it and produce a new string without printing out? I know of "printf" which prints out  a result, but I don't need a result to be printed out.

Comment: You are looking for [`snprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html) and its relatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is `sprintf`: it's exactly `printf` to a buffer.

Comment: Please don’t recommend `sprintf`, but always `snprintf` or similar.

Comment: @M.M: Everything is okay if used correctly. Nonetheless, bugs exist. They exist because humans make mistakes and do not use things correctly. To deal with this, we have debeloped various techniques to guard against and reduce errors. snprintf is one such. Safe-programming techniques should be promoted.

Comment: Unless the return value of `snprintf()` is checked (for negative and too great), the rump generated string is itself a problem.  Neither `snprintf()` nor ``sprintf()` should be used if the destination is insufficient..

Comment: Oh, well, if I'd said `snprintf` someone would have complained that Microsoft has a better ... oh, wait, they already did.

Comment: @M.M: How can you use `sprintf` correctly in a way that is meaningfully distinct from reimplementing `snprintf`’s feature of computing the length of string produced by a format and argument list?

Comment: @DavisHerring by knowing the size of the things you're printing, e.g. `unsigned int x;  ..... char buf[3]; sprintf(buf, "%u", x % 100);`

Comment: @DavisHerring You do so by providing a buffer of appropriate size and by not being a fool. If you're concerned, you can indeed use `snprintf`. But the question was what you'd use in place of `printf` -- which is also vulnerable to buffer overflows, stack corruption, and any number of other sutle ass-biters.

Comment: @M.M: I’ll grant the utility of having the size statically (so you can use automatic storage).  But I tend to think of that as an optimization: the 3 and the `%100` are critically and invisibly connected.

Answer (score 2):

You want `snprintf`.  Just like `printf`, but you give it a destination buffer and a size.  (The size is important, so `snprintf` can be sure not to overflow it.)  Use it like this:

```
char outbuf[100];
snprintf(outbuf, sizeof(outbuf), "%d %f %s %c", 1, 2.3, "four", '5');
```